# how to fix "can't read property push of undefined" error in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, push

I have coded a simple app to learn Nodejs but when i run "nodemon index.js" in cmd i have this error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

i have follow all instruction in the udemy course for learn nodejs
and i faced this problem when i separated the file into two files index.js and genres.js

genres.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router;

//simple data 
const genres = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'course1'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'course2'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'course3'
    }
];

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////// Get //////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(genres);
});

router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {

    const genre = genres.find(c => c.id ===
        parseInt(req.params.id)); //req.params.id return string 
    if (!genre)
        return res.status(404).send('The course is not found...');

    res.send(genre);

    res.send(req.params.id);
});

router.get('/:year/:month', (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.params);
});

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const {
        error
    } = validategenre(req.body);
    if (error)
        return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

    const genre = {
        id: genres.length + 1,
        name: req.body.name
    }
    genres.push(genre);
    res.send(genre);
});

router.put('/:id', (req, res) => {

    const genre = genres.find(c => c.id === parseInt(req.params.id));
    if (!genre)
        return res.status(404).send('The course does not exist !!! ');

    const result = validategenre(req.body);
    if (result.error)
        return res.status(400).send(result.error.details[0].message);


    genre.name = req.body.name;
    res.send(genre);

});

function validategenre(genre) {

    const schema = {
        name: Joi.string().min(3).required()
    };
    return Joi.validate(genre, schema);

}

module.exports = router;
```

index.js

```
const Joi = require('joi');
const genres = require('./routes/genres');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();


app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api/genres', genres);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listining on port ${port}...`));
```

Comment: You might consider using consistent indentation when writing code - it'll make read and debugging it much easier, not only for potential answerers, but for you as well.

Answer (score 13):

In genres.js, you should import

```
const router = express.Router();
```

instead of

```
const router = express.Router;
```

Also, the error you mention could be from any `push` in your code (without any more info), please specify the stacktrace next time :)

Comment: Thank you very much it finally worked i can't imagine that was the problem 
it's a first time to code NodeJS ,
and i will specify the stack trace next time :))

Answer (score 0):

Use `const router = express.Router()` instead of `const router = express.Router`.

Answer (score 0):

## It can be wrong variable name :)

I made a mistake due to intelligence in my quick sample -

Typically signature of a ReST call is
router.get("/something", (req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
**response**.write("test");
**response**.end();
});

Here if you will notice I was using response where as i was suppose to use res

Moreover ensure you have registered your routes using
app.use(router);