# How to solve "cannot read property 'push' of undefined in node.js

Tags: node.js

I have two files one is 'a.js' in compressed folder and another b.js in a folder b within compressed folder and i am using routing of express.i am a beginner and don't know how to resolve this error  and what does it mean.I want to use b file in a.js.
**a.js**

````
```var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var route=require("./b/b");
app.use("/b",route);
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/btn.html'));
});

app.post('/c', function (req, res,next) {
  console.log('ist MD');
  next();
});
app.post('/c', function (req, res,next) {
  console.log('snd MD');
  next();
});
app.post('/c', function (req, res,next) {
  console.log('third MD');

});

app.listen(3000);
````

**here is b.js**

```
   const express=require("express"); 
const Router=express.Router; 
Router.get('/',(req,res)=>{ console.log("i am file b");
 });
 module.export=Router;
```

**This is error**

```
C:\Users\Palwasha\Downloads\Compressed\b\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:502
```

this.stack.push(layer);
             ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at Function.route (C:\Users\Palwasha\Downloads\Compressed\b\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:502:14)
    at Function.proto.(anonymous function) [as get] (C:\Users\Palwasha\Downloads\Compressed\b\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:509:22)
    at Object. (C:\Users\Palwasha\Downloads\Compressed\b\b.js:3:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to fix "can't read property push of undefined" error in Nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53902424/how-to-fix-cant-read-property-push-of-undefined-error-in-nodejs)

Comment: I cannot see where in Your code You're doing `.push()`  find that file and put it to Your question

Comment: i have not written anything like push in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create & reference an *instance* of `Router`

```
const express = require ('express');
const router = new express.Router();

router.get('/',(req,res)=>{ console.log("i am file b"); });

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: it solves my problem but what was the error saying?

Comment: @palo internally Router's store handlers in an array, the callstack is telling you it's trying to push the route into a non-existent property (most likely a property that's only initialized when the Router is).